# How to remove action bar tabs padding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I am using android support libraries to create TabBar.I am able to create TabBar successfully with my own modifications using styles but I don't know why is there left padding in first tab and right padding in second tab.I am not able to remove those by overriding styles.

**layout file code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java File code :**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_contacts);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                    .setTabListener(tabListener));
        }}
```

**My code for style is:**

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBar.Tab</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/My.TabText.Style</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar.Tab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="My.TabText.Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <!-- <item name="android:ellipsize">none</item> -->
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    </style>
```

I have attached the screenshot below for reference.

[image]

Comment: please post your layout xml.

Comment: @nurealam11 I have added xml file code and java code as well.

Comment: please try this. I hope it will help you. http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/06/android-action-bar-with-tab.html

Comment: @nurealam11 what is wrong with my code.It's same as you have mentioned in the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the answer to my own question.I couldn't remove the padding but I apply the same background color to the space in left and right.I used the following code :

```
 <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TabBar</item>

<style name="MyActionBar.TabBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/gray_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is kinda a hack... And unfortunately doesn't work in my case :< since my selected tab has a different background colour